# Why does the console cout some wrong letters after memcpy of a char*

Tags: c++, buffer, memcpy

I copy a `char*` to a `char*` and get it back and `cout`it.

```
char buffer[100] = { 0 };
char* name = "foo";
int bar = 12345;
memcpy(buffer, &(bar), 4);
memcpy(buffer + 4, name, 3);

int result = 0;
memcpy(&result, buffer, 4);

char backname[3];
memcpy(backname, buffer + 4, 3);

std::cout << result << std::endl;
std::cout << backname << std::endl;
```

Why does it show this:

```
12345
foo╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠90
```

but `strcmp(backname,"foo")`does let me know that they match?

---

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Yes and it let me know that the right values are inside of `backname`it just displays something wrong else i wouldn't ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things I would fix:

1. Use `sizeof(int)` instead of `4`. This is most likely not the real issue.
2. `backname` is not a null-terminated string the way you are using it. Use:

   ```
   char backname[4] = {0};
   memcpy(backname, buffer + sizeof(int), 3);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if there is no null at the end of the char* it does print some memory stuff? So in the end i need one more char to be 0 at the end?

Comment: Yes. If you don't have a null at the end of a string, you are going to access memory that are out of bounds, which results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks alot for the clearence. I wonder why the strcmp works correct.

Comment: @BennX _"I wonder why the strcmp works correct."_ Because it ends comparing characters, if there was one `'\0'`was hit from the inputs . Character literals automatically add a `'\0'` at the end.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Heck. Thanks for the clearance and yes already noticed it myself. And I’m sorry that I didn’t came across null-termination yet.

Comment: @BennX [`std::strrcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) has undefined behaviour when dealing with strings that aren't null-terminated. Your standard library implementor decided to play nice.